# How to substitute part of date string with table.field value in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE count (nbr int not null);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE day (day int not null);
```

Table count has 3 records with field values:
1
2
3

Now I want to insert a **calculated** date in table day based on the current date and a value from table count with the following statement:

```
insert into day values (date('now', '+'(select nbr from count where nbr=1) 'day'));
```

No matter what I change and (re)try in the statement I keep getting 'Syntax error' messages or the message that day.day may not be NULL.

Is it possible to use the select statement in this case anyway (with correct syntax of course) and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was only a matter of correct concatenation.
This works:

```
insert into day select (date('now', '+'||(select nbr from count where nbr=1)||' day'));
```